# Call capistrano tasks in the root namespace from different namespace?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano

If I've made a namespace and trying to call a task from another namespace:

```
namespace :mystuff do
  task :mysetup do
    unicorn.restart
  end
end
```

I'm getting an error.

```
=> undefined method `reload' for #<Capistrano::Configuration::Namespaces::Namespace:0x00000102ab32d8>
```

How do I reference the root namespace?

Answer (score 1):

Try calling it using invoke:

```
invoke 'unicorn:restart'
```

Normally you would do this as part of an `after` or `before`.  In your case, probably `after`:

```
after "mystuff:mysetup", "unicorn:restart"
```